# laravel left join property of non-object when no result

Tags: laravel-5

I am creating an application with 3 models: bookstore, shelve and book. All 1-to-many relations.

When I want a list of all shelves: I do:

**Controller:**

```
$shelves = Shelve::leftJoin('books', 'books.shelve_id', '=', 'book.id')->paginate(5);
```

**Blade:**

```
@if ( !$shelves->count() )
    No shelves
@else
@endif
```

This works fine when there is at least 1 shelve created. When there are no shelves (empty table), I get `Trying to get property of non-object`.

What can I do?

Comment: Try `dd($shelves)` when there is no shelves. See what returns.

Comment: Please post the code that passes the $shelves from controller to the view.

Comment: return view('report.shelves', compact('shelves'));

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(!isset($shelves))
      no shelves
@else
@endif
```

Try this! You are trying to count what doesn't exist that's why it's giving an error.